# A short notation to fix the assumption that all involved parameters are, say, positive

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Often I make simplifications or other operations with assumptions. Sometimes the assumptions simply state that all parameters involved are positive.

I wonder, if there is a short notation for such a situation?

Just to give some code

```
Simplify[expr[a,b,c,d,e,g,f],{a>0,b>0,c>0d>0,e>0,f>0}]
```

I dream about something like

```
 Simplify[expr[a,b,c,d,e,g,f],All>0]
```

This expression is, of course, a nonsense, but may be something in this direction.

Do you know something of this sort?

Comment: `Simplify[expr[Sequence @@ #], Thread[# > 0]] &@{a, b, c, d, e, g, f}` ?

Comment: @belisarius Why do not you format this as the answer?

Comment: @belisarius That's not really saving key strokes...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries True, but you can pack it as in the last example in my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have version 10, you can also use [`AllTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html):

```
h[x__] :=Sign@Times[x]

Simplify[h[Sequence @@ #], AllTrue[#, Negative]] &@{a, b, c}
(* -1 *)

Simplify[h[Sequence @@ #], AllTrue[#, Negative]] &@{a, b, c, d}
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Thank you, AllTrue is what I looked for. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Alexei, thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

One way is:

```
Simplify[expr[Sequence @@ #], Thread[# > 0]] &@{a, b, c, d, e, g, f}

(* expr[a, b, c, d, e, g, f] .... Simplify has nothing to do in this simple case*)

g[x_, y_] := x + Abs@y
Simplify[g[Sequence @@ #], Thread[# > 0]] &@{a, b}

( a + b *)
```

packing it:

```
g[x_, y_] := x + Abs@y
simpWithAssump[symb_, vars_] := Simplify[symb[Sequence @@ #], Thread[# > 0]] &@vars
simpWithAssump[g, {a, b}]
(* a + b *)
```

Comment: Thank you, it is, indeed a way. I should have thought about it. Thank you.